# how can one best create multilingual javadoc?

Tags: javadoc, multilingual

I am involved in a project and someone is putting in bunches of good stuff, but it is coming with javadoc in both English and Japanese. He is doing this in, for example, method comments:

```
    /**
     * Return really great stuff.
     *
     * <span class="en">By the way, here are some details.</span>
     * <span class="ja">Here are the details in katakana...</span>
     */
```

There is a snippet of js put into the header of the generated javadoc and it works pretty well. It senses your browser's language and only shows you the correct comment.

So, how do I get rid of these darn messages when generation javadoc:

```
    OurUtils.java:139: warning - Parameter "delivery" is documented more than once.
```

Is there a way we could be doing this that is more kosher? Any other approaches that will work as well?

thanx - ray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't mention the `@parameter delivery` twice:

```
/**
 * @param delivery
 * <span class="en">By the way, here are some details.</span>
 * <span class="ja">Here are the details in katakana...</span>
 */
```

Comment: Oh. My. God. :-) What can I say. Yep. That's really good. Or I am just that stupid. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer does not work, but the answerer could not know that. The problem is that most of us use eclipse and people like the javadoc that one sees from doing a mouse-over on a method, field or class. If one does the trick above, one can have the javadoc show the right thing when one is displaying it in a web page. But when one is displaying a fragment of a page in another application, there is no way to apply the CSS to get the desired result.

What I am thinking I will do is create a doclet that pre-processes the source. It will pick out the elements that hve either no language tag or the correct language tag and create a copy of the source specific to just that language. Then the javadoc generation can proceed normally.

Either that, or this doclet will generate the javadoc itself and not produce an intermediate source. We will see.